# How can i get whole data as a json file after i scrape

Tags: node.js, json, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

In node.js I try to make a web **scraping** project using Axios and I can see the whole information when I console.log it but when I try to make a JSON file with that data I can get just the first element on the data can you help me, please!!!!

```
  "use strict";

  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  const axios = require('axios');
  const cheerio = require('cheerio');
  const jsdom = require('jsdom');
  const fs = require('fs');
  const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
  const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

     
    
class dataToCsv {
constructor() {
    this.getData();
}
async getData() {
   try {
    const KeyWord = 'laptop'
    const url = `https://www.amazon.com/s?k=${KeyWord}&ref=nb_sb_noss_2`;

    axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
            let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
            $('span.a-size-medium').each(async function (i, e) {
              let names = await $(e).text();   
                 let datas = '{ "employees" : [' +
                             `{ "firstName": ${names}}]}`;

                let dataJsons = await JSON.stringify(datas, null, 2);

                fs.writeFile('./data/student-2.json', dataJsons, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Data written to file');
                });  
          });

            $('span.a-offscreen').each(async function (i, e) {
              let prices = await $(e).text();   
                 let datas = '{ "employees" : [' +
                             `{ "firstName": ${prices}}]}`;

                let dataJsons = await JSON.stringify(datas, null, 2);

                fs.writeFile('./data/student-3.json', dataJsons, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Data written to file');
                });  
          });

        }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
   
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
   }
}

 }
 new dataToCsv();
```

Here is the JSON Output:

```
{
 "prices": "$239.99"
}
```

OK, I figured out the get data issues but now I can't get the data with the multiple lines. here is the new code

```
async getData() {
   try {
    
    const KeyWord = 'laptop'
    const url = `https://www.amazon.com/s?k=${KeyWord}&ref=nb_sb_noss_2`;

    axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {

            let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

            let names = $('span.a-size-medium').text()
            let prices = $('span.a-offscreen').text()

            let datas = {
                        "name": names,
                        "price": prices,
                }
                let dataJsons = JSON.stringify(datas, null, 2);

                fs.writeFile('./data/data.json', dataJsons, (err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('Data written to file');
                }); 

        }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
   
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error);
   }
}
```

and JSON output be like that

{
"name": "Acer Swift 3 Thin & Light Laptop | 14" Full HD IPS 100% sRGB Display | AMD Ryzen 7 5700U Octa-Core Processor | 8GB LPDDR4X | 512GB NVMe SSD | WiFi 6 | Backlit KB | FPR | Amazon Alexa | SF314-43-R2YYAcer Swift 3 Intel Evo Thin & Light Laptop, 14" Full HD, Intel Core i7-1165G7, Intel Iris Xe Graphics, 8GB LPDDR4X, 256GB NVMe SSD, Wi-Fi 6, Fingerprint Reader, Back-lit KB, SF314-59-75QCAcer Aspire 5 A515-46-R14K Slim Laptop | 15.6" Full HD IPS | AMD Ryzen 3 3350U Quad-Core Mobile Processor | 4GB DDR4 | 128GB NVMe SSD | WiFi 6 | Backlit KB | Amazon Alexa | Windows 10 Home (S mode)Newest_HP Pavilion 15.6 Inch FHD Laptop Computer PC for Business Student with 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 Processor 8GB RAM 512GB SSD WiFi HDMI Bluetooth Webcam Windows 10 Home 1-Week AimCare SupLenovo IdeaPad 3 15.6" Laptop: Core i5-1165G7, 12GB RAM, 512GB SSD, 15.6" Full HD IPS Touchscreen Display, Backlit KeyboardSAMSUNG Galaxy Book Pro Intel Evo Platform Laptop Computer 15.6" AMOLED Screen 11th Gen Intel Core i5 Processor 8GB Memory 512GB SSD Long-Lasting Battery, Mystic BlueHP 14-ds0061cl Stream 14" HD A4-9120e 1.5GHz 4GB RAM 32GB eMMC Win 10 Home S White (Renewed)2021 Newest Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Business Laptop, 15.6" Full HD Touchscreen, Intel Core i5-1035G1, 16GB DDR4 RAM, 512GB PCIE SSD, Online Meeting Ready, Webcam, Wi-Fi, HDMI, Windows 10, BlackHP Stream 14 inches HD(1366x768) Display, Intel Celeron N4000 Dual-Core Processor, 4GB RAM, 64GB eMMC, HDMI, WiFi, Webcam, Bluetooth, Win10 S, Royal Blue(Renewed)Newest HP 17.3" HD+ Display Laptop, Intel Quad-Core i3-1005G1 Processor, 16GB Memory, 1TB HDD, DVD, Webcam, Numeric Keypad, WiFi, HDMI, Windows 10 Home, Silver, Oydisen ClothASUS ZenBook 13 Ultra-Slim Laptop, 13.3” OLED FHD NanoEdge Bezel Display, Intel Core i7-1165G7, 16GB LPDDR4X RAM, 512GB SSD, NumberPad, Thunderbolt 4, Wi-Fi 6, Windows 10 Pro, Pine Grey, UX325EA-XS74TOPOSH 11.6 inch 2 in 1 Laptop Tablet Computer with Touch Screen, Intel Celeron Quad Core N4120 8GB RAM 256 GB SSD- SilverHP Pavilion Premium Laptop (2021 Model), 15.6" FHD Display, AMD Athlon N3050, AMD Radeon Graphics, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, Thin & Portable, Micro-Edge & Anti-Glare Screen, Long Battery Life, Win10ASUS TUF Gaming F17 Gaming Laptop, 17.3” 144Hz Full HD IPS-Type, Intel Core i7-11800H Processor, GeForce RTX 3050 Ti, 16GB DDR4, 512GB PCIe SSD, Gigabit Wi-Fi 6, Windows 10 Home, TUF706HEB-DB74HP 15 Laptop, 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 Processor, 8 GB RAM, 256 GB SSD Storage, 15.6” Full HD IPS Display, Windows 10 Home, HP Fast Charge, Lightweight Design (15-dy2021nr, 2020)ASUS Laptop L410 Ultra Thin Laptop, 14” FHD Display, Intel Celeron N4020 Processor, 4GB RAM, 128GB Storage, NumberPad, Windows 10 Home in S Mode, 1 Year Microsoft 365, Star Black, L410MA-DB04Portable Monitor - Lasitu 100% sRGB Super Thin 15.6 Inch Metal Frame Portable Screen USB C/HDMI Gaming Monitor for Laptop/PC/Cellphone/PS3-5/Switch/Xbox with Foldable CaseHP 14 Laptop, AMD Ryzen 5 5500U, 8 GB RAM, 256 GB SSD Storage, 14-inch Full HD Display, Windows 10 Home, Thin & Portable, Micro-Edge & Anti-Glare Screen, Long Battery Life (14-fq1021nr, 2021)Acer Swift 3 Thin & Light Laptop | 14" Full HD IPS 100% sRGB Display | AMD Ryzen 7 5700U Octa-Core Processor | 8GB LPDDR4X | 512GB NVMe SSD | WiFi 6 | Backlit KB | FPR | Amazon Alexa | SF314-43-R2YYHP Stream 11.6-inch HD Laptop, Intel Celeron N4000, 4 GB RAM, 32 GB eMMC, Windows 10 Home in S Mode with Office 365 Personal for 1 Year (11-ak0010nr, Royal Blue)Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Business and Student Laptop (2021 Latest Model), 15.6" HD Display, Intel N4020 Dual-Core Processor, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD, Webcam, HDMI, Bluetooth, Wi-Fi, Black, Windows 102021 HP 15.6" Thin Laptop, Intel N4020, 8GB RAM 128GB SSD Webcam, 1-Year Office365, Wi-Fi, Dual Core up to 2.8 GHz, Windows 10 S, FHD Display,

"price": "$629.99$749.99$649.99$849.99$361.40$399.99$629.00$699.00$638.49$249.90$269.99$277.98$299.99$379.99$419.99$309.00$279.00$399.00$399.99$2,611.49$1,116.99$1,499.00$900.00$1,099.99$172.00$799.00$264.00$659.99$1,099.99$359.00$549.00$1,299.00$535.00$659.99$279.99$149.99$549.00$629.99$749.99$233.48$559.00$419.00$77.99$97.45$172.50$171.00$299.99$379.00$499.00"
}

Comment: You are writing to file for EACH of the 'span.a-size-medium' and 'span.a-offscreen' elements. Looks like it's just overriding the file each time ("$239.99" is probably the last price, yes?). You need to save the data outside of the each loop. It also looks like you are trying to JSON.stringify a string, which does not seem right.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What output are you expecting, exactly?

Comment: hi, I edited the code you can check it. @nonethewiser